# Etymology of testosterone-charged men?

Tags: etymology

A couple of weeks back I read the story *2 States: The Story of My Marriage* by Chetan Bhagat. In the story, I found a weird phrase: *testosterone-charged men*. What is the etymology of that phrase **testosterone-charged men**?

> *"I’d have much preferred her place, as I didn’t want her to be the only woman in the dorm with twenty **testosterone-charged men**"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only citation including it in the whole of the Oxford English Dictionary is dated 1997. *Testosterone* itself is the anglicised form of German *Testosteron*, first recorded in 1935. That in turn is a combination of *testis* ('testicle') and *sterone* ('formative element in the names of some steroids').

Comment: :Thanks for your quick response..I just found the general meaning of that word..But i wondered,Is there any slang meaning of that word??

Comment: @VijinPaulraj: None that I know of, but it's an expression that might sometimes be used with humourous intent.

Answer (score 1):

> But i wondered,Is there any slang meaning of that word??

Testosterone is a hormone. Although it exists in females as well, it is regarded by the general public as a hormone responsible for male-style behaviour. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/testosterone) lists the literal meaning of the word, and then the figurative meaning of the word:

> 1. (biochemistry, steroids) Steroid hormone produced primarily in the testes of the male; it is responsible for the development of secondary
>      sex characteristics in the male.
> 2. (figuratively) Manly behavior, often of an aggressive or foolishly reckless nature. *Mother encouraged James to rely more on intelligence
>      and less on testosterone to deal with the neighbor's son.*